# Maven compile error ProjectBuildingException

Tags: java, maven, sdk, alfresco

terminal error

[image]
Compilation Error while running the project.

Line 18 error

[image]

This the line 18.

Comment: 10 was given by default. Should I remove 10

Comment: You should _rename_ `10` to something valid like `chapter10`, `exercise10`. For package naming conventions see [Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Answer (score 1):

Java package names should be lower case and begin with letters.
Like **something10.platformsample** instead of **10.platformsample**.